# Differential equation with sec

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, definite-integrals

[image]

With $(a)$ I got that $-y^2 dx = \sec^2x\ dy$, but it makes no sense. Hence, no Idea how to handle $(b)$.

Comment: For $(i)$, since $0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2$, I think we can use the facts that $\cos x\le1$ and $\sin x +\cos x\ge1$. Divide them by $\cos x$ and combine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

For $(a)$, using separation of variables, we obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{y^2}&=-\frac1{\sec^2x}\ dx\\
\int y^{-2}\ dy&=-\int \cos^2x\ dx\\
\int y^{-2}\ dy&=-\int\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}\ dx.
\end{align}

Comment: For $(i)$, since $0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2$, I think we can use the facts that $\cos x\le1$ and $\sin x +\cos x\ge1$. Divide them by $\cos x$ and combine.

Answer (score 1):

Using separation of variables and a little more rearranging (you almost had it), we get the following:

$$\int \cos^2(x)dx = \int \frac{-1}{y^2}dy$$

I simply took what you already had and divided both sides by $-y^2$ and $\sec^2(x)$.  Now it's just a matter of good old integration. :)